# Definir o ItemsSource de um ComboBox dentro de um ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, combobox, template, mvvm

Olá, tenho um ComboBox dentro do ItemTemplate de um ListBox, os itens desse ListBox são definidos a partir de um ObservableCollection no ViewModel, e cada item dessa lista é um objeto com uma lista(**ListaDe**) de opções dentro que deveriam ser mostradas no ItemsSource do ComboBox, mas não consigo defini-las com o Binding.

Segue código para análise:

```
<DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <gi:GIComboBox Width="100" Height="20"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListaDe}" />
                        <gi:GILabelSubtitulo Content="----->" />
                        <gi:GIInputText Height="20" Width="100" Margin="10 0 0 0" Mask=""/>
                        <gi:GIBotaoComum Height="20" Width="30" Content="..." Margin="10 0 0 0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
```

O Binding não deveria funcionar já que cada item do ListBox representa um objeto na minha lista?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, você está certo. O `DataContext` do `DataTemplate` é o próprio dado que está sendo representado, ou seja, cada item da lista.
Para fazer o binding funcionar corretamente, você deve deixar explícito o local que ele deve olhar. Por exemplo, você pode falar para ele procurar o primeiro ancestral do tipo `ListBox` e ver o valor do `DataContext.ListaDe` dele (suponde que o `DataContext` dele seja a ViewModel).

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.ListaDe}"/>
```